# How to send messages correctly to another Class Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, message, nsview, class-method

My project is some kind of a timing application for Mac OS X and it looks like I have problems to understand how to make things work together :)

What I did so far:

**1.** An `NSObject` Class `TimeController` which starts a timer and modifies some `NSTextEdit`s on a one second base.

**2.** An `NSView` Class `TimeCircle` which is connected to a custom view (top right in the image) which I want to draw a circle with two lines representing the progress after I hit **Start**.

**3.** Imported `TimeCircle.h` in `TimeController.m`

**4.** Set up a class method `+ (void) callFromOutside` which I send a message when the timer in **1** is running. `[TimeCircle callFromOutside];`  this works.

This is the method in `TimeCircle.m`:

```
+ (void) callFromOutside {
 [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

The problem is that `callFromOutside` receives the message correctly but complains:
**Class method '+setNeedsDisplay:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**

How can I trigger `callFromOutside` to get my Circle updated correctly?

I´m obviously doing things wrong. I also tried to connect `TimeController` to my `NSView` but `TimeController` is an `NSObject` class and I can't connect it.

Any clues?

[image]

Ronald

Comment: Make it an instance method instead of a class method.

Comment: This is what I tried before. But an instance method seems to be not recognized when trying to set it up. When writing [TimeCircle callFromOutside]; I get ahead typing after the first few characters only for class methods. So I thought it is invalid, wrong? No I get an error: Class method '+callFromOutside' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: Thing is, you need a reference to the *specific instance* you want to send the message to. Imagine having multiple of these time circle views on the screen, which one should update itself when you call `callFromOutside`? You need to specify that. Sending a message to the class itself only works for class methods (as you've seen), but you cannot call instance methods (such as `setNeedsDisplay:`) from a class method, because `self` refers to the class in a class method...

Comment: mmh, I think I´m aware that I cannot setNeedsDisplay or drawRect. This is why I use callFromOutside which is an instance method in TimeCircle and I put [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] there, where self is TimeCircle. Shouldn´t that work?  >>you need a reference to the specific instance you want to send the message to << I haven't heard of this. What do you mean? callFromOutside is for this one and only NSView purpose and nothing else. I´m somehow lost.

Comment: I don't think you have a clear understanding of the difference between class and instance methods. Yes, if you make `callFromOutside` an instance method (indicated by `-` instead of `+`), you can use `setNeedsDisplay:` inside it, but you cannot send this message to `TimeCircle` *because that is the class and not an instance*.

Comment: Yes, you are right what my understanding of class and instance methods is. I haven't done too much in ObjC so far. Up to today I've only used instance methods. But what can I do that my circle gets drawn?